# Modulo returns a Template parse errors

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to code a very simple calendar displayer for my ionic app (it's basically just Angular). I'm storing informations for each date in an array `displayedCal`. 
It bugs when I'm trying to make a new row for each week using `*ngIf="(i%7)==0"` : this gives me a parse error. What would be the correct way of doing this?

```
  <template ngFor let-d [ngForOf]="displayedCal" let-i="index">
    <ion-row *ngIf="(i%7)==0">
      <ion-col (click)="...">{{d.displayedDate}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row *ngIf="(i%7)==0">
  </template>
```

Note to non-ionic developpers `<ion-row>` and `<ion-col>` are pretty much like a `<tr>/<td>` structure ...

N.B.: If I just remove the `ngIf` my code is actually working.

Comment: Does it work without the parenthesis?

Comment: `ngIf` applies to the whole block, not just your line of code. the final ngIf doesn't make sense here. What do the contents of displayedCal look like?

Comment: Try with `*ngIf="(index%7)==0"`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It's an array of 28 elements (4 weeks); for each 28 date I got :

`displayedCal = [{displayedDate: '15/05'', fullDate: 'Monday the 05th of May', toDo: 'a set of actions to do', author: 'the author of the action', isDone: boolean}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngIf` applies to the whole block, not just your line of code. But even if this would work it still doesn't make sense for your purpose.

You could change your `displayedCal` array to a multidimensional array in this form: `displayedCal[week][day]` and then make a nested loop:

```
<template *ngFor="let week of displayedCal">
  <ion-row *ngFor"let day of week">
    <ion-col (click)="...">{{day.whatever}}</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</template>
```

However date and time is a delicate matter. You should consider your data model carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to do a `[week][day]` structure because it kind of breaks my other features workflow. Anyways since it did not work as I wanted I finally adopted your pattern and this is what I came up with :

```
  <template ngFor let-week [ngForOf]="displayedCal" let-i="index">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col *ngFor="let day of week" (click)="...">{{day.displayedDate}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </template>
```

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: Cheers :) A good data model will save you tons of time in future development